# Minor help in the factorisation techniques used in lec notes

Tags: polynomials, factoring

If anyone could help me see how
$$
A(\xi,\eta)=a\,\xi_x^2+2\,b\,\xi_x\,\xi_y+c\,\xi_y^2=0
$$
is turned into
$$
\frac{1}{a}
\left[a\,\xi_x+\left(b-\sqrt{b^2-ac}\right)\xi_y\right]
\left[a\,\xi_x+\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-ac}\right)\xi_y\right]=0.
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to expand the second expression?

Comment: I haven't. I was taking it for granted that it should be obvious to me.

Comment: Well, if you just expand the second expression, you should find it is very similar to the first.

Comment: This is a straight forward application of the quadratic formula. You just have to treat $\xi_x$ as the variable and "ignore" $\xi_y$

Comment: Isn't this similar to a^(2)+2ab +b^(2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{a}
\left[a\,\xi_x+\left(b-\sqrt{b^2-ac}\right)\xi_y\right]
\left[a\,\xi_x+\left(b+\sqrt{b^2-ac}\right)\xi_y\right]=\\
=&\frac{1}{a}\left\{a^2\,\xi_x^2+
a\left(b\color{red}{+\sqrt{b^2-ac}}\right)\xi_x\xi_y+
a\left(b\color{red}{-\sqrt{b^2-ac}}\right)\xi_x\xi_y+
\left[b^2-\left(\sqrt{b^2-ac}\right)^2\right]\xi_y^2\right\}=\\
=&\frac{1}{a}
\left\{a^2\,\xi_x^2+2\,a\,b\,\xi_x\,\xi_y+
\left[\color{blue}{b^2}-\left(\color{blue}{b^2}-ac\right)\right]\xi_y^2\right\}=\\
=&\frac{1}{a}
\left\{a^2\,\xi_x^2+2\,a\,b\,\xi_x\,\xi_y+a\,c\,\xi_y^2\right\}=\\
=&a\,\xi_x^2+2\,b\,\xi_x\,\xi_y+c\,\xi_y^2.
\end{align}
$$
Or, if you prefer, you can read this bottom to top.